# Launching OpenOffice filters from a menu/toolbar button

Tags: xslt, filter, openoffice.org

I have packaged an XSLT export filter for OpenOffice as per the instructions on this page:
   http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Filter_extensions

It works fine; but in order to be used, the user has to select the command 'File/Save as' then choose the correct file extension that triggers the use of the filter, and a target file name.

I would like to let the users launch the filter by using either a menu item or a toolbar button, without asking them for anything (the target file name is defined within the transformation).

What is the best way to do that and packaging it in the same extension as the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much fruitless searching and asking, it turns out the best trick is to write a macro that launches the filter, and associate that macro with a button; the macro and the button can be packaged in the same extension as the filter.